# SaveChangesAsync in Microsoft.Data.Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, dbcontext, entity-framework-core

I am migrating an existing solution to Entity Framework core from Entity Framework 6. I realised that there are no async operations (i.e. SaveChangesAsync) in EF Core. Is this completely removed from EF Core ?

-Alan-

Comment: it is still in the source code: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/92989dae4874b3bd2b06662a801f1e9b6127b8a2/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational/Storage/RelationalDatabase.cs Are you missing a reference?

Comment: have you added the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational package to your app? does it work now?

Comment: @magicandre1981, I gave up on EF7 and leave the solution in EF6. I'll wait till a stable version is released

Comment: stable EFCore 1.0 is now out. ave you tried it again?